# gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to local socket

Tags: usb, 16.04, gps

I am trying to get a BU-353 GPS device to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via GPSD. When I ran `cgps` I was greated with a timeout error.

I assumed something was wrong with the GPS because I has not been used in a while so I ran `gpsmon`. The gps had gained a fix on multiple saltiles and had acquired my lat and long.

This lead me to believe that something must be wrong on the GPSD side so I ran the command `gpsd -N -D3 -F /dev/ttyUSB0`. I was met with:

```
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to local socket /dev/ttyUSB0
gpsd:ERROR: control socket create failed, netlib error -1
```

Even when I directed GPSD to the socket with `gpsd -N -D3 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock /dev/ttyUSB0`, (code lifted directly from [the GPSD troubleshoot page](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/troubleshooting.html)) I was still receiving the same error.

I have no clue what is going wrong. I am very new to GPSD and not very comfortable with Ubuntu more generally so maybe I am making a simple mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A BU-353 should work out of the box with gpsd.  But you have a a few things going on,

- the first item is [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) is in charge of launching an instance of gpsd. Until it is turned off (`sudo service gpsd stop`) you will be chasing your tail.
- `-F` Creates a control socket for device addition and removal commands.  It must be a valid pathname on your local filesystem. It is doubtful your control socket would possibly be the USB gps you're trying to read. Typically the control socket is `/var/run/gpsd.sock` but could be `/tmp/anything`
- you need to have write permissions to open the control socket. `sudo gpsd -N -D3 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock` works, while `gpsd -N -D3 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock` will fail because non-privileged user cannot write to the control socket. Likewise, `gpsd -N -D3 -F /tmp/when_pigs_fly` should work. (But, none will work if a gpsd is already running.)

Additionally you must consider additional instructions in `/etc/default/gpsd` For example,

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS=""
```

These are introduced in `/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service` as an `EnvironmentFile`

The first line is useless.  `systemd` is in charge and does not fork off the process.  It runs with the `-N` flag.

I set USBAUTO="true" because gpsd's use  of `udev` and hotplugging is fairly transparent-.  Plug in something that's a gps and it works.  If it's not gps, it minds it's own business.

But I do code in the location of a gps that I'm currently working with.  Because, stopping/restarted gpsd without rebooting, the gpsd won't 'know' about the gps at `/dev/ttyACM0` (or wherever it is) without a hotplug event.  I code in the location to not have to un/plug the gps every time I restart gpsd without a reboot.

Other `GPSD_OPTIONS=` could include `-n` `-G` or `-b` at your discretion.

Additionally, there are other test clients (`xgps`) that are more robust for checking gps output, but that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's permissions - get the same error on a raspberry that is just adding/running the command with sudo/root permissions.

sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock

Comment: is this a solution or a comment?

Comment: Please add some more details to describe what you are suggesting.

Comment: I had `service gpsd start` -> `sudo service gpsd start`